# Wrong css on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-safari

Hi I just started develop applications for mobile devices, Have the next trouble. This site: http://dimax.co.il/development/test-ding/OscarWilde/#/menu dispalyed correctly on PC browsers, but on Safari on iPhone 4S, it should be displayed full screen but it much less then full screen. All css you can see there. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have view port set in your head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

A more complete answer for mobile sites would be:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this will do it now